# iPhone/Objective-C - Searching for a specific word within a string

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsstring

Is there a way to search for specific words within a string in Objective-C?

Let's say I have the following sentence:

thequickbrownfox

If I wanted to search for "quick" within the sentence. What would be the best way to achieve this?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
if ([myString rangeOfString:stringToSearch].location != NSNotFound) {
    // stringToSearch is present in myString
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [NSString::rangeOfString](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html) for this.
From the docs -

> **Return Value**
> An NSRange structure giving the location and length in the receiver of the first occurrence of aString. Returns {NSNotFound, 0} if aString is not found or is empty (@"").